# Are all RISC-V argument registers caller saved even if unused by the call?

Tags: assembly, calling-convention, riscv, abi

The [RISC-V ABI](https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/riscv-calling.pdf) lists the argument registers `a0-a7` as caller saved.

In any given function, does this always apply, regardless of how many argument registers that function uses? i.e. Is a `void(void)` function free to use all 8 `aX` registers without any saving? (Barring of course when it calls other functions)

Answer (score 3):

> Are all RISC-V argument registers caller saved even if unused by the call?

Yes.

But better to call them call clobbered or scratch than caller saves/saved.

"Callee saves" registers, better referred to here as call preserved, are saved *and restored* by callees: if the callee wants to use them, on the presumption that someone else higher in the call chain is also using those registers.  The existing value in a call preserved register is saved somewhere, and that exact value is restored to that exact register before returning to the caller.

By contrast in actual usage, caller saves registers are unlikely to be saved *and then restored back*.  Values in those registers are assumed to be clobbered by a function call, so any value in a call clobbered register, if needed after the call, is moved somewhere that will survive the function call — which could be memory or into a call preserved register.  After the function call, those values are used from wherever they were moved, and, there's no reason to "restore" them to the same register they came from.  So, the pairing of save & restore is not necessarily symmetrical as is the case with call preserved (callee saves) registers.

In real usage, it is the value in the register that *may* be saved somewhere for later use, but only if needed, while the register itself is not really saved and restored.